# How do I build a webserver deployable release in Angular2?

Tags: angular

I reproduce the official quickstart tutorial for Angular2 and all works like expected, but now I want release this app to my webserver. How do I build a release in the Angular2 way and where can I find my packaged static app files?

In ember.js I did a call like

```
ember build --env production
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an angular-cli based on the ember-cli project, but at this moment it's a work in progress.

[angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli)

Comment: Thank you, it works but I'm a bit surprised about the size of an empty new build app ... 20 MB in the dist folder :-/